# Proof that categorical product and coproduct of vector spaces is their direct sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

It is stated in Tom Leinster's Basic Category Theory Example 5.2.5, but it doesn't have a proof, and I can't find online any. (I only need it for two vector spaces. I think it is untrue for infinite many vector spaces.)

Comment: Well, have you tried showing that $V\oplus W$ satisfies the definition of "product" and "coproduct" for vector spaces $V$ and $W$?

Comment: No, but I don't really want to. Actually someone just claimed that the categorical product of vector spaces is their tensor product, I wanted to show a proof against it, and I couldn't find any. (I think I searched waay more time than to provide a proof for him, but then I can't even use equations there, and such.) 
So this is more of a knowledge sharing question that meant to provide a searchable and linkable reference for this fact. Maybe someone takes their time to answer it, to cultivate the common knowledge or earn some SE points